# Code with # comment not formatting correctly

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

[This revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15452701/revisions) involved removing some extraneous `#` signs and indenting some of the code.

However, I found that the code gets displayed as markdown. I selected it and hit the code block. I even tried to do it twice, with no luck.

It still gets formatted as a title.

Comment: Yes, code inside a list needs an extra 4 spaces.

Comment: It's not within a list, though, is it? It's two lines down.

Comment: As far as the parser is concerned, it is.

Comment: Isn't a double-newline in markdown supposed to signal a 'reset' of sorts in formatting?

Comment: @Qix No, it does not.  It signals the start of a new paragraph.  Numeric bullets can be multi-paragraph.

Comment: Doesn't quite work like that when lists come into play (as it is OK to have the next item with a double newline before hand).

Comment: Huh alright, @Oded if you make that an answer I'll accept.

Comment: You can use `<!>` to 'reset' the indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lists [do not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255179/code-with-comment-not-formatting-correctly?noredirect=1#comment23669_255179) reset after any amount of whitespacing.**

Therefore, code blocks *must* be indented by 8 spaces instead of 4 when they follow a list element.

A [workaround suggested by Dukeling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255179/code-with-comment-not-formatting-correctly?noredirect=1#comment23681_255179) shows you can reset this behavior by using `<!>`. Example:

1. This is a list

```
This is code that immediately follows the list, indented by 4 spaces.
```

Comment: Writing formatting-related answers make me cringe because examples always look so ugly.