# Why can't I correct the formatting on this answer?

Tags: support, markdown

I was going through the first-posts queue and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771065/1217087). It's correct, but the formatting was a little off, so I thought I'd fix it for them.

Turns out though, that the formatting is/was correct (codeMagic "fixed" it) - but the markdown parser is considering the code part of the answer to be a part of the list. Note the extra indentation.

See my example below. If you click edit on this question, you'll see that there's multiple lines between the list and the `<string>` tags. This should terminate the list section and start the code formatting section. It doesn't matter whether the tags are present or not - though if they are present, they don't show up.

1. List item 1.
2. List item 2.

   This should be code formatted.

However, if you put any (?) non-whitespace text at least 1 line after the list, it "fixes" it:

1. List item 1.
2. List item 2.

.

```
<string>This should be code formatted.</string>
```

Is there a workaround for this?

I have tried this in 2 other Markdown editors (Atom editor, and dillinger.io) and both exhibit the behaviour of requiring 2 line breaks between the list and the code.

Comment: Put at `<!-- -->` between the list and the code, with empty lines before and after.

Comment: Note that I took the lazy man's fix for the edit. <tsk tsk>

Comment: That works. I mostly was just hoping to be better than codeMagic.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265765/code-not-appearing-in-code-blocks) was posted today, and *might* be related to what you're looking for. Might have read your question too quickly, but hope not...

Comment: Yeap, that's exactly the same issue. Is there likely to be a fix for this, or is this a quirk of some custom logic in the SE Markdown editor?

Comment: @AdamS congratulations! You have accomplished what most only dream of

Comment: Looks like this has been [brought up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255179/1217087) before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get around it by putting an Html comment between the list and the code

```
<!-- -->
```

This will separate the list and the code.

1. So,
2. For example

```
This is some code, not in the list
```

Also handy when you want to separate other elements, like 2 code blocks.

```
Code line 1
```

```
Code line 2
```

Comment: [Tested and confirmed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24771065/revisions)...thanks